# Employer-provided private medical insurance start date

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance

I started a new employment about a month ago.

One of the main reasons for accepting the offer is that they offer comprehensive medical insurance.

The company "benefits guide" has details of this insurance cover and this was emailed to me along with my contract by the CTO of the company. In this guide is says:

"This is an optional benefit you can join from the **first day of your employment**".

However, a few days after joining I inquired with HR about the insurance and they replied saying that is was only available after 3 months and they sent me the benefits guide which indeed said 3 months. I just assumed I had made a mistake and didn't think much of it.

However today I have become quite unwell and need to be seen by a doctor out of hours. They had said I need to go for some diagnostic tests but there is a waiting time (unsurprisingly). Due to this I checked the benefits guide that was emailed to me along with my contract and this does say that it's available from day 1. So obviously the CTO made a mistake and sent me an old version of the guide. However I relied on this when I agreed to join the company, and now I want to make use of the benefit.

So my question is: Does this benefit start date form part of the contract even though it's not specifically mentioned in the contract that I signed ?

[I wan't sure if I should post this on law.se so apologies if this is the wrong place - if so, can it be moved ?]

Comment: @JoeStrazzere so they can just change this as they please ?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I just assumed I had mis-read it in the guide they sent me prior to signing and therefore didn't have a choice. It was only a week before Christmas that the HR person sent me the updated version, and then they were off early for Christmas, and what with the build-up to Christmas plus getting my legs under the table with a new job, I just didn't prioritise looking into it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It just doesn't seem right that they can entice a new employee with certain benefits and then substantially change those benefits after the person starts, even though  it may have been a mistake. It's their mistake, not mine, but I have to live with the consequences and cost (if I were to go private on my own) ?

Comment: @Joe indeed, that's what I intend to do, but I was just hoping to find out the legal position in UK employment law first. I guess I should have posted this at law.se :(

Comment: Just one thing to clarify. In the past, I have joined schemes where I couldn't claim for the first X months. I was still enrolled from day one. That isn't what has happened here, is it?

Comment: I don't have experience with the UK, but in the USA there are options to continue insurance from previous employment (COBRA).  Does the UK have anything similar?  Even though your employment is ended you might have a grace period for continuing the old insurance.

Comment: @mattfreake thank you. The offer letter, sent along with the contract, says: *"Additionally, you will be enrolled into the company health care scheme and, if you pass [3 months] probation, the company share scheme."*

Comment: Wayne, you missed Matt's point. Even if you had been enrolled, you may not have been eligible to claim anyway. That is what they are suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

It's almost certainly the case that you would need to sign additional documents in order to be enrolled in the company healthcare plan. The healthcare plan is probably structured as a three-way contract between the three parties.

As [Hilmar's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181893/employer-provided-private-medical-insurance-start-date/181895#181895) states, it's unlikely that the health insurance company is going to care one iota about whatever is in any documentation that has been provided to you. It's just not their problem. They don't have a signed agreement with you, and that's all that matters.

It's likely to be a hassle for your employer to pay for your out-of-pocket expenses themselves. What your employer is willing to do probably depends strongly on whatever correspondence has already been had on the matter (before you developed your condition).

Comment: Thanks (+1). I'm not looking for reimbursement of expenses because I haven't incurred any, and doubt that I will. I would be happy if they enrol me once I bring it to their attention, but I wanted to explore the legal issues first, in case they refuse and want to stick to the 3 months.

Comment: As for correspondence, there is just the email I received from the CTO with the benefits guide, and an "offer letter" that states *"Additionally, you will be enrolled into the company health care scheme and, if you pass [3 months] probation, the company share scheme."*. There is no more corresponce on the matter apart from the email to/from HR that I already mentioned, after I joined.

Comment: @WayneB I suspect that because you didn't make a big fuss of it when you joined, it's unlikely they'll be willing to bend much on the issue. Of course, the nature of insurance is you think it's more important once you need it.

Comment: I only didn't make a fuss because I haven't had chance to yet ! The HR person has been on annual leave since - they are back on Tuesday.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this benefit start date form part of the contract even though it's not specifically mentioned in the contract that I signed ?

That's currently not the most important question.

You can argue that you "should have been enrolled" based on the offer and contract document that have been given and signed. You may be able to enroll before the 3 months are up, but no insurance is going to pay for any costs incurred before the enrollment date.

> I just assumed I had made a mistake and didn't think much of it.

You sure did make a mistake, if that left you without coverage. You should have followed up with HR and ask them how you were supposed to handle health insurance during the first three months. Don't accept an answer like "Well, let's just hope you don't get sick".

Best you can do is to reach out to HR: let them know that your contract states clearly "benefit is available from day one" and insist that they enroll you right away. If they point to the existing benefits guide, let them know that this guide was NOT part of your contract that you signed and that you have not agreed to the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks (+1). The thing is that I was only notified about it a week before Christmas and the HR person has been away since. I have also just checked the "offer letter" that they sent along with the contract and that says *"Additionally, you will be enrolled into the company health care scheme and, if you pass probation, the company share scheme"* so this is quite clear that I should have been enrolled since day 1.

Answer (score -1):

You could try contacting the insurance company for clarification.

But this will be an insurance product, from an insurance company. They aren't going to pay out if someone else has made a mistake over when the policy starts.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I believe that the company has changed the policy start date recently and the CTO just made a mistake by sending me the old version. So it used to be from day 1, but now it's after 3 months. Had this mistake not have been made I would not have joined. I genuinely don't know what I have done wrong here.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks. What was the mistake please ? Are you saying I should have brought it up then and there ? Obviously I couldn't have brought it up earlier, and the HR person has not been in the office since.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere unfortunately that's not a financial possibility for me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The OP is from the UK. The public healthcare system is a lot better than what people from the USA are accustomed to. It's far less of a pressing need to have private healthcare cover.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well, it's not a boolean thing. He is likely to get a better quality of care with private healthcare, but the absence of private healthcare cover doesn't mean he will be made bankrupt if there is a serious medical condition that needs treating.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Unless it's dental, but most dental issues can wait 3 months.

Comment: @WayneB It's not about whether or not *you* have made a mistake.  If the company hasn't started the policy, then you aren't insured.  Maybe if you badger HR enough, they may start the policy earlier.  Or they may fire you during the probationary period, because you don't "fit in".